# I want to ask, how can I disconnect tkinter's .bind

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

I've been experimenting recently
Found that I can drag, move the button or the configuration inside

But I keep trying to let go and never follow
But there's no way, stop
.bind. I have used if and button switches and still can't do it, I hope someone can help me think of a way

What I want is to call out the picture, and it can be dragged to the specified position to place it, moved over and pressed to move, and it will move with it.

The newcomer posts, if the post offends the engineers, I will apologize to everyone first.

```
import tkinter as tk
new_x =50
new_y =50
mgs=False
def click():
    global mgs
    if mgs ==False:
        mgs =True
        
        root.after(1000,move)
    else:
        mgs =False

# def B1Motion():
#     root.bind("<B1-Motion>",move)
def aa(event):
    global new_x

    global new_y
    new_x = event.x
    new_y = event.y
    # print(new_y)
    # print(new_x)
    print(new_x,new_y,"\r",end="",flush=True)
    
def move(event):
    # global new_x

    # global new_y
    # new_x = event.x
    # new_y = event.y
    # super event.x
    # super event.y
    new_x = event.x
    new_y = event.y
    c.place(x=new_x, y=new_y)
    # self.after(1000, increment_textOne)
    # b.place(x=new_x, y=new_y)
    # print(new_y,"\r",end="",flush=True)
# def even(event):
#     while True:
#         root.bind("<B1-Motion>",move)


# --- main ---
# command=move
root = tk.Tk()
a = tk.Button(root, text='it')
b = tk.Button(root, text='Move it',command=click)
root.bind("<B1-Motion>",aa)
# root.bind("<B1-Motion>",move)
# while break_program == True:
#     new_x = event.x
#     new_y = event.y
#     b.place(x=new
#     _x, y=new_y)
#     print(event.x)
#     time.sleep(5)
c=tk.Canvas(root,bg="red",height=40, width=40)
# root.bind("<B1-Motion>",move)
# c.bind("<Enter>",even)
root.bind("<B1-Motion>",move)
# root.bind("<B1-Motion><FocusIn>",move)
# if c.event.type =="Enter":
#     root.bind("<B1-Motion>",move)
# root.after(1000,click)
b.place(x=100,y=100)
a.place(x=20,y=20)

print(new_x)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code would be much easier to understand if you removed the commented-out sections, and included just enough code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter provides the `unbind(seq,callback)` for this.

After binding an event you get a reference to that binding and with this reference you can unbind your callback from the event, like in the example below.

```
import tkinter as tk

def OnEnter(event):
    global motion_binding
    motion_binding = canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', OnMotion)
def OnLeave(event):
    canvas.unbind('<B1-Motion>',motion_binding)
    canvas.unbind('<Enter>',enter_binding)
    canvas.unbind('<Leave>',leave_binding)
def OnMotion(event):
    x,y = event.x,event.y
    canvas.coords(rectangle, x,y,x+100,y+100)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,bg='blue')
rectangle = canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill='red')
enter_binding = canvas.bind('<Enter>', OnEnter)
leave_binding = canvas.bind('<Leave>',OnLeave)
print(enter_binding)
canvas.pack()
```